# Change svg tekst item on select with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a small weather site, on this site there is a page where you can see the temperatures in each part of holland. I've also created a select item where you can select "today", tomorrow or after tomorrow.

I want to change the temperatures when someone selects a different day.
I've made an if-else statement in js to change the temperatures, but for some reason, it doesn't work. I've searched a lot but can't find out why...

Picture of the page:

[image]

By the way, everything is in dutch...

My select in HTML with the text items I want to change:

```html
<p>
    <label for="dagen">Kies de dag:</label>
    <select id="dagen" name="dagen" onchange="kaartGrades()">
        <option value="vandaag">Vandaag</option>
        <option value="morgen">Morgen</option>
        <option value="overmorgen">Overmorgen</option>
    </select>
</p>
<div class="weer_kaart">
    <img id="kaart" src="picto/kaart-nederland-jan-hi.png" alt="nlkaart" height="500px">

    <svg style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <text id="s1" x="175" y="200" fill="red">5&deg</text>
        <text id="s2" x="310" y="135" fill="red">7&deg</text>
        <text id="s3" x="150" y="300" fill="red">5&deg</text>
        <text id="s4" x="300" y="280" fill="red">6&deg</text>
        <text id="s5" x="200" y="370" fill="red">4&deg</text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

And the js code to change the tempratures of the text items:

```js
function kaartGrades() {
  const x = document.getElementById("dagen").value;
  alert(x);
  if (x === "vandaag") {
    document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("s2").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("s3").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("s4").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("s5").innerHTML = "";
  } else if (x === "morgen") {
    document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML = "8&deg";
    document.getElementById("s2").innerHTML = "9&deg";
    document.getElementById("s3").innerHTML = "8&deg";
    document.getElementById("s4").innerHTML = "9&deg";
    document.getElementById("s5").innerHTML = "10&deg";
  } else if (x === "overmorgen") {
    document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML = "10&deg";
    document.getElementById("s2").innerHTML = "13&deg";
    document.getElementById("s3").innerHTML = "12&deg";
    document.getElementById("s4").innerHTML = "12&deg";
    document.getElementById("s5").innerHTML = "15&deg";
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/gh0krzm4/1/

Comment: @Terry's fiddle ^ works for me too.

Comment: @Ronny Your script is working fine just need to play with css because of your SVG is not covering whole height of top image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is *working fine* just need to play with `css` properties because of your `SVG is not covering whole`**`height`** of top image so define `position:absolute` on svg something like below snippet.

```js
function kaartGrades() {
  const x = document.getElementById("dagen").value;
  alert(x);
  if (x === "vandaag") {
    document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("s2").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("s3").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("s4").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("s5").innerHTML = "";
  } else if (x === "morgen") {
    document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML = "8&deg";
    document.getElementById("s2").innerHTML = "9&deg";
    document.getElementById("s3").innerHTML = "8&deg";
    document.getElementById("s4").innerHTML = "9&deg";
    document.getElementById("s5").innerHTML = "10&deg";
  } else if (x === "overmorgen") {
    document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML = "10&deg";
    document.getElementById("s2").innerHTML = "13&deg";
    document.getElementById("s3").innerHTML = "12&deg";
    document.getElementById("s4").innerHTML = "12&deg";
    document.getElementById("s5").innerHTML = "15&deg";
  }
}
```

```css
.weer_kaart{
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.weer_kaart svg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <label for="dagen">Kies de dag:</label>
    <select id="dagen" name="dagen" onchange="kaartGrades()">
        <option value="vandaag">Vandaag</option>
        <option value="morgen">Morgen</option>
        <option value="overmorgen">Overmorgen</option>
    </select>
</p>
<div class="weer_kaart">
    <img id="kaart" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RadlM.jpg" alt="nlkaart" height="500px">
    <svg>
        <text id="s1" x="175" y="200" fill="red">5&deg</text>
        <text id="s2" x="310" y="135" fill="red">7&deg</text>
        <text id="s3" x="150" y="300" fill="red">5&deg</text>
        <text id="s4" x="300" y="280" fill="red">6&deg</text>
        <text id="s5" x="200" y="370" fill="red">4&deg</text>
    </svg>
</div>
```